# Dados recebidos via Request usando Doctrine precisam ser tratados?

Tags: php, doctrine, http-request, request, silex

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto novo, é a primeira vez que estou usando `Doctrine` com `Silex` e estou com dúvida quanto ao recebimento de informações através de formulários.

Eu recebo os dados dos `forms` através do `Request` do `Symfony` (`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`) e queria saber se preciso usar algum método para filtrar esses dados tipo `filter_input`, `htmlspecialchars`, `strip_tags`, etc?

No meu caso eu recebo esses dados assim:

```
$dados = $request->request->all();
```

e pego eles em:

```
$dados['nome']
```

por exemplo. Preciso tratar ou não?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo código (*`source`*) do [Request](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Request.php) e consequentemente [ParameterBag](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/ParameterBag.php), pode ser utilizado da seguinte forma que já obtêm o que se espera:

```
$id = $request->request->getInt('id'); 
$nm = $request->request->getAlpha('name');
$st = $request->request->getBoolean('status');
```

ou especificar o seu próprio ***filtro***:

```
$mail = $request->request->filter('id', 0, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

no caso mencionado `all()`, não são tratados os dados, mas, como foi relatado existe a opção onde possa ser feito isso com `filter` ou os implementados `getInt`, `getAlpha`, `getBoolean`, `getDigits` e `getAlnum` que internamente utilizam esse tipo de código, exemplo `getBoolean`:

```
public function getBoolean($key, $default = false)
{
    return $this->filter($key, $default, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
}
```

O [Doctrine - Security](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/security.html) possui uma parte de segurança, mas, isso pode ser complementado com o código exemplificado logo acima, ou até mesmo uma ***Classe de Validação***, pode barrar a maioria dos problemas encontradas no desenvolvimento Web com dados obtidos mediante requisições [http](/questions/tagged/http).

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

- [Request](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Request.php)
- [ParameterBag](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/ParameterBag.php)
- [34. Security - Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/security.html)

Comment: Obrigado Virgilio pela ajuda.. certo.. isso eu realmente não sabia que dava para fazer, mas ai te pergunto, é necessário fazer isso usando o doctrine? ouvi falar que o doctrine se encarrega de filtrar os campos que vão ser salvos. Posso estar falando bobagem, não tenho muito conhecimento sobre o assunto.. pode me auxiliar? Grato

Comment: @AlexandroZaleski, não posso confirmar que o `Doctrine` faça isso internamente, eu teria que fazer a mesma coisa que acabei de fazer verificando o código do `Doctrine`, mas, eu faria desse jeito da resposta, porque, já mandaria para o Doctrine o dado mais completo e sem quase problemas. Eu uso Laravel e eu mesmo faço isso com Eloquent, não mando dados sem verificar, apesar que eu faço isso mediante Validação (Validation).

Comment: Certo.. Muito obrigado @VirgilioNovic pela ajuda, acho que segurança nunca é demais.. vou usar dessa forma para não depender do doctrine para validações que precisam ser feitas antes de serem enviadas para o banco certo? Muito obrigado novamente..

Comment: Ok @AlexandroZaleski, validar é sempre bom. Se tiver uma Validação entre eles já vai sanar a maioria dos problemas

Comment: @VirgilioNovic excelentes dicas sobre Symfony!

Comment: Vlw @GuilhermeNascimento ... !

Answer (score 1):

Completando a resposta do @Virgilio Novic, o que diz a [documentação](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/security.html) do Doctrine:

> In general you should assume that APIs in Doctrine are not safe for user input. There are however some exceptions.

Tradução livre:

> Em geral, você deve assumir que as APIs em Doctrine não são seguras para inputs do usuário. Existem, no entanto, algumas excepções.

As excepções podem ser vistas nos seguintes links:

- [SQL Injection: Safe and Unsafe APIs for User Input)](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/security.html#sql-injection-safe-and-unsafe-apis-for-user-input)
- [User input and Doctrine ORM](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/security.html#user-input-and-doctrine-orm).

Repare o que diz a secção **12.2.1. Wrong: String Concatenation** (concatenção de strings), você nunca deve nunca construir suas consultas dinamicamente e concatenar inputs do utilizador em sua consulta SQL ou DQL. Para Doctrine não há absolutamente nenhuma maneira de descobrir quais partes do SQL são inputs do usuário e quais não são.

Por exemplo:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '" . $_GET['username']. "'";
```

Embora DQL é um wrapper em torno do SQL que pode proteger contra algumas implicações de segurança, o exemplo anterior também é uma ameaça para consultas DQL, que no fim resultará em uma query:

```
$dql = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = '" . $_GET['username'] . "'";
```

Nesse cenário, um invasor ainda pode passar um nome de usuário definido como `'OR 1 = 1` e criar uma consulta DQL válida.

## Então, como tornar as consultas mais seguras?

- [Prepared Statements](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/security.html#right-prepared-statements): você deve sempre usá-lo para executar suas consultas. É um procedimento de duas etapas, separando a consulta SQL dos parâmetros. Eles são suportados para consultas DBAL SQL e consultas ORM DQL.

Exemplo DQL:

```
$dql = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = :name";
$query = $em->createQuery($dql);
$query->setParameter("name", $_GET['username']);
$data = $query->getResult();
```

Exemplo SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = $connection->executeQuery($sql, array($_GET['username']));
```

Veja mais informações sobre como utilizá-lo [aqui](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#using-prepared-statements).

- [Quoting/Escaping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/security.html#right-quoting-escaping-values): Embora anteriormente disse que a concatenação de string está errada, há uma maneira de fazê-lo corretamente usando o método de `Connection#quote`. Esse método está disponível somente para SQL, não para DQL. Para DQL é sempre encorajado a usar `Prepared Statements` não só para segurança, mas também para razões de cache.

Exemplo:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = " . $connection->quote($_GET['username'], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

## Dados recebidos via Request usando Doctrine precisam ser tratados?

Depende da API que está a ser usada conforme referido na [documentação](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/security.html#sql-injection-safe-and-unsafe-apis-for-user-input), mas de um modo geral se a query está sendo construída com base no input do utilizador, sim, é necessário tratar todas as entradas.

Comment: Estou usando DQL nas querys e faço como você postou ali usando o `setParameter` mas mesmo assim então preciso tratar as os dados recebidos via `input`. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @AlexandroZaleski o `Prepared Statements` é suficiente, não é preciso mais do que isso, aliás os exemplos na própria documentação não utilizam mais nada. Os métodos `getInt`, `getBoolean` no fundo servem mais para garantir que o sistema receba os tipos esperados. Imagine que está a espera de uma string, o utilizador pode enviar `' OR 1=1` na mesma que irá passar na sua validação, se tratando de uma string.

Comment: @FelipeMorais Eu estava olhando, estava verificando meu código, no caso do inserir e do alterar, eu estou somente pegando os dados da entidade, dando um persist e um flush, não estou passando pelo DQL, neste caso preciso usar os filtros né? fiquei confuso agora..

Comment: @AlexandroZaleski não precisa, veja aqui: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/security.html#user-input-and-doctrine-orm o método `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager#persist()` é seguro contra SQL injection.